Understanding Bianchi identities in Newman-Penrose formalism
In the classical paper by Newman & Penrose, the authors introduce their formalism. However I am a bit confused over the Bianchi identities (4.5), in their paper. The first in particular reads:
$$D\psi_1-\overline{\delta}\psi_0=-3\kappa \psi_2+[2\epsilon+4\rho]\psi_1-[-\pi+4\alpha]\psi_0$$
The authors state that it can be derived from the equation (2.9) in the paper, which reads:
$$R_{mn[pq;r]} = \gamma^{\phantom{s}l}_{m\phantom{s}[r}C_{pq]ln}-\gamma^{\phantom{s}l}_{n\phantom{s}[r}C_{pq]lm}+2C_{mnl[p} \gamma^{\phantom{s}l}_{r\phantom{s}q]}$$
However I don't see how the Bianchi identity I have reported comes from this expression, since I have:
$$D\psi_1=-C_{1213;1}\qquad \overline{\delta}\psi_0=C_{1313;4}$$
and I don't see how the indices match: there is a $2$ in the first and a $4$ in the second.

Why do you want the indices to match?

@TimRias Because in the formula for the Bianchi identity there is a $[pq;r]$

There is a bunch of useful identities you get from the fact that the Weyl tensor is trace free. These should allow you to relate the $12$ with the $34$ index pairs.
